# Buscador Secuencial y Binario

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un buscador binario y secuencial de tipo generico pero tengo algunos problemas en la clase prueba; tengo la clase buscador secuencial pero no es de tipo generico

```
    package Buscador;

    public class Buscador {


    public class Buscador_binario<E extends Comparable<E>> {
        private E[] a;

        public Buscador_binario(E[] palabras) {
            a = palabras;
        }

        public int buscador(Comparable<E> v) {
            int bajo = 0;
            int alto = a.length - 1;

            while (bajo <= alto) {
                int med = (bajo + alto) / 2;
                E medVal = a[med];
                int resultado = v.compareTo(medVal);

                if (resultado < 0) {
                    alto = med - 1;
                }

                else if (resultado > 0) {
                    bajo = med + 1;
                } 

                else {
                    return med;
                }
            }

            return -1;
        }
    }
    }
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Esta es mi clase prueba:

    package Buscador;

    public class Prueba {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] palabras = {"Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", 
                "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", "Juliet", "Kilo", "Lima", 
                "Mike", "Noviembre", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", 
                "Sierra", "Tango", "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "X-Ray", 
                "Yankee", "Zulu"};
          //Me marca un error  Buscador.Buscador_binario<String> Buscador = new 
 Buscador.Buscador_binario<String>(palabras); 
            System.out.println(Buscador.buscar("Noviembre"));
            System.out.println("Si esta en la lista");
            System.out.println(Buscador.buscar("Octubre"));
            System.out.println("No esta en la lista");
        }
    }

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Y esta es mi clase de buscador secuencial

    public  int busquedaSecuencial(int []arreglo,int dato){
     int posicion = -1;
      for(int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++){//recorremos todo el arreglo
          if(arreglo[i] == dato){//comparamos el elemento en el arreglo con el buscado
        posicion = i;//Si es verdadero guardamos la posicion
        break;//Para el ciclo
       }
     }
     return posicion;
    }
```

Comment: El error que te da en en el new Buscador_binario es que la clase Buscador_binario está dentro de la clase Buscador por lo que tendrías que hacer algo así: Buscador.Buscador_binario<String> buscador = new Buscador.Buscador_binario<String>(palabras);

Comment: Hola, gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ver mi pregunta; pero me sigue marcando un error me dice: "an enclousing instance contains Buscador.Buscador_binario is required" actualice lo que he corregido

Comment: No entiendo por qué pones `Buscar.Buscador_binario` cuando no está definida la clase buscar en ningún lado... en todo caso sería `Buscador.Buscador_binario`.

Comment: @DavidDPG, tienes razon fue un error de dedo pero de igual manera me marca error "an enclousing instance contains Buscador.Buscador_binario is required"

Comment: ¿Puedes poner los nombres de los ficheros donde tienes cada clase y pegar el código fuente completo de cada uno de los ficheros? Mencionas al final que tienes una clase de buscador secuencial pero no se ve por ninguna parte la palabra clave class ni en que fichero está.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]!. Por favor, no añadas ruido a tu pregunta con esos caracteres repetidos al final de la misma. Un saludo.

Comment: Estás tratando de instanciar una clase (La clase `Buscador_binario`) que es interna de otra (la clase `Buscador`). La sintaxis para instanciar estos constructos es un poco diferente. Puedes revisar la doc de java (en inglés) [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) para investigar sobre el tema.